# Как получить токен сессии из полученных значений? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

решил я расшифровать куки Laravel без собственно его использования. Посмотрел как они расшифровываются в их файле и написал аналог:

```
function decrypt($payload = 'cookie')
{
    global $key;
    $payload = getJsonPayload($payload);
    $payload['value'];
    $iv = base64_decode($payload['iv']);
    echo $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($payload['value'], 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, $iv );
}
```

Всё работает вроде бы, все данные, которые зашифрованы в базе таким образом расшифровываются на ура. Но вот когда пытаюсь расшифровать куки, то получается такая история:

```
67e37f4b5c997344e6d31dfw36ce023260238be6|QxWrlAcjHN7hngfzJK4afyhnCleZaFR6QnafMjwF
```

Перекопал всё, не понимаю что делать с этими значениями, по идее по итогу должно получиться одно значение (remember_token):

```
bI3YAIr8pPeW4lWv1bZ1cSFTqhN3firZIdoFEZMUwNol4D42f7dGJAZfn0Qu
```

который хранится в базе данных пользователей, но что-то идёт не так.

Понимаю что я занимаюсь скорее всего извращенством и проще было бы сделать через Laravel, но всё таки буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Дл начала посмотрите как и С чем зашифровываются печеньки в Laravel, копайте глубже. Вам вряд ли удастся расшифровать его вне приложения.

Comment: Да я вроде всё прокопал, оно берет значение сессии шифрует и ставит его, а в итоге при дешифровке получается вот это. Остальное ведь расшифровать не проблема, только с куками такой трабл

Comment: Читайте и узучайте код [EncryptCookies](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.html) middleware, в нем вся соль, конкретнее [Encrypter](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php)